# What is the right way to duplicate data in Firebase?

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, database-design, relational-database

I've been refactoring my code recently to try and denormalize my Firebase database. I understand that some duplication and redundancy is necessary, but I'm finding it hard to settle on the right level of duplication.

For example, in my project I have `outfits` and `items`, where an `outfit` may have many `items` tagged in it.

Currently, I have this setup:

```
outfits
  outfitId
    outfitName
    outfitDescription

items
  itemId
    itemName
    itemDescription
    itemBrand

itemsByOutfit
  outfitId
    itemId
      itemName
      itemDescription
      itemBrand
    itemId
      itemName
      itemDescription
      itemBrand
```

In the UI, I often need to get a list of `outfit` objects, and the items tagged.  `itemsByOutfit` is a convenient index in this sense - because I can get the name, description, and brand all in one go.

But when it comes to renaming an item or changing the description, I have to fan out the update, too.

Would it be better to keep `itemsByOutfit` restricted to just the `itemId` value? Like this:

```
itemsByOutfit
  itemId: true
  itemId: true
```

That seems simpler to maintain, but more work when fetching. I'd presumably have to make a second query using all the `itemId` values to get the name, brand, etc.

I also have another index - `itemsByBrand` - which follows a similar duplication pattern. All data is duplicated and organized by brand - for example:

```
itemsByBrand
  Nike
    itemId
      itemName
      itemDescription
      itemBrand
```

I'd appreciate any thoughts or best practices that might help me build a more scalable solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My view is that you only hold the item data (name, description, brand) once ie. in the items node. All other itemby'x' lists are itemId:bool lists that you read to get the necessary items and then you iterate through the returned list to retrieve the item data. Shouldn't be much of a performance overhead and the data volumes involved are minimal.